# How to integrate Actor IM android app with local server

Tags: android, server, chat, messenger

I am working with Actor Instance Messaging Platform and for now, I have installed and run it's local server, and also imported and compiled the android app in Android Studio. Now I want to configure the android app to work with the local server I have, but I have no idea where to apply the configurations and settings.
Here is the link to the project's [repository in GitHub](https://github.com/actorapp/actor-platform).

Has anyone ever worked with it or has any idea about how I can integrate these two?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, by the way the application's development team have introduced the solution to this problem in their newly released documentation, which I post the link to it here.

[Actor Documentation](https://developer.actor.im/docs/android-sdk-endpoints)

Comment: Please elaborate. I have give the endpoint tcp://192.168.1.101:9070 in android client but it doesn't connect to my server.

My server specs - Ubuntu 14.04 installed

Comment: the link is unavailable